# rosserial-windows sync with device lost

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using [rosserial for windows](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows) and followed the  [instruction](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World).
This works fine, I even build a dll of that, quite similiar to this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/223231/building-dll-of-rosserial_windows/).
I can send the tutorial message Hello World in my vb.Net program by using this DLL.
Now I am trying to send a message with some IMU data, by using a timer in my vb.Net program which calls a function in my DLL. Unfortunately on the Linux side the following message appears "Sync with device lost"

The same message without the timer but with a loop works. Here is the working code of my DLL

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PublishData_Something( double x, double y) {
ros::NodeHandle nh;
char *ros_master = "100.111.0.222:11411";//
//printf("Connecting to server at %s\n", ros_master);
nh.initNode(ros_master);
powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInput extPoseInput_msg;
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);
nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);
while (1)
{
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.x = x;
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.y = y;
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.z = 0;
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.x = x;
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.y = y;
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.z = 0;
    extPoseInput_msg.gripper.movement = 0;
    extPoseInput_msg.gripper.rel_acceleration = 0;
    extPoseInput_msg.gripper.rel_velocity = 0;
    cmd_vel_pub.publish(&extPoseInput_msg);
    nh.spinOnce();
    Sleep(100);
}
```

}

this works, the message is send to the Linux computer, but as mentioned I want to use a timer in my vb.net application, so the message can be updated. So I changed the function above
Here is the code of the message which throws the error "Sync with device lost"

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PublishData_GripperNeu(double rel_vy, double y) {
ros::NodeHandle nh;
char *ros_master = "100.111.0.222:11411";//'
nh.initNode(ros_master);
//printf("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInput extPoseInput_msg;
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);
nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);
extPoseInput_msg.robot.rel_velocity = 0; 
extPoseInput_msg.robot.rel_acceleration = 1;
extPoseInput_msg.gripper.rel_acceleration = 1;
extPoseInput_msg.gripper.rel_velocity = (float)rel_vy;
extPoseInput_msg.gripper.movement = y;
extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.z = 0;//Setzen der nicht veränderten Werte auf null
extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.x = 0;
extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.y = 0;
extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.w = 0;
extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.x = 0;
extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.y = 0;
extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.z = 0;
//Publish Message
cmd_vel_pub.publish(&extPoseInput_msg);
nh.spinOnce();
```

}
Now the warning on the Linux side appears  "Sync with device lost" every time this message is published.
The Biggest difference between this two messages are that the second one do not use a loop because the loop is the timer in my vb.net application.
That is wrong with my second message?

---

Edit: Thank you gvdhoorn

First I make a declaration and then the first function is InitialRos()

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
char *ros_master = "100.111.0.222:11411";//
powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInput extPoseInput_msg;
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall InitialROS() { 
  nh.initNode(ros_master);
  nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);}
```

which I call only once.

and other function, which I call by a timer

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PublishData_Gripper(double rel_vy, double y) {

  ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);
  nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.rel_velocity = 0; //
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.rel_acceleration = 1;//
  extPoseInput_msg.gripper.rel_acceleration = 1;
  extPoseInput_msg.gripper.rel_velocity = (float)rel_vy;
  extPoseInput_msg.gripper.movement = y;
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.x = 0;
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.translation.y = 0;
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.w = 0;
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.x = 0;
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.y = 0;
  extPoseInput_msg.robot.rotation.z = 0;
  cmd_vel_pub.publish(&extPoseInput_msg);
  nh.spinOnce();}
```

In this version the message "sync with device lost" appears when the first function InitialRos() is called

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277848/rosserial-windows-sync-with-device-lost/) by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
Can you clarify why you appear to be re-initialising the connection each and every time your callback is executed? Why not setup your `NodeHandle` and `Publisher` once, and then re-use them inside the callback body?

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2017-12-20**:
First I splited the function PublishData_GripperNeu into two parts. Initialisation and PublishData
But then I got the error "sync with device lost" in Linux when I clicked on a button in my vb.net application which called only the initialisation function. At that point no message was send

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2017-12-20**:
only the topic was advertised by nh.advertide(cmd_vel_pub);

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
Without knowing more about *how* you split things up (ie: show your program), it's going to be hard to say why that happened.

If you make sure things are ordered properly, and all necessary parts stay in scope, it should work.

Re-initing everything each and every callback will most likely not.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
I see this in your edit in your callback function:

```
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);
nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);
```

There should be no need to recreate the `Publisher` or call `advertise(..)` again. You've already done that.

Only update and pub the msg in the callback.

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2017-12-20**:
I didn't see that, I will correct this.
Thank you very much
But do anyone know what "sync with device lost" mean?
Can it be something with spinOnce()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it by calling spinOnce periodically on the windows side before any messages is send

Edit: Here a code snippet(Thanks to gvdhoorn)

First I declare all important variables at the beginning of my DLL like this

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;                                  
char *ros_master = "111.222.0.111:11411";//here you have to put your IP:PORT !!!
char *topic="cmd_vel";
powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInputextPoseInput_msg;  
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub(topic, &extPoseInput_msg);
```

Then the export functions follows. The function ROS_SpinOnce is the one you have to call periodically in your application before you initialize the node and advertise the topic. It only executes spinOnce

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ROS_SpinOnce() {
    nh.spinOnce();
}
```

After you started to call spinOnce periodically, you have to initialize and advertise like this. It has to be called only once.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall InitialROS() { 
    nh.initNode(ros_master);
        nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);
}
```

After that you can publish so many messages as wanted in another functions like below. If you call Publish functions periodically in  your application you have to add nh.SpinOnce
either in your DLL-functions or by calling ROS_SpinOnce() in the timer event.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PublishData_Gripper(double rel_vy, double y) {
    extPoseInput_msg.robot.rel_velocity = 0;
    ....
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) with karma: 43 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
On which side?

Could you perhaps add a small example (ie: code) to your answer?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
I fixed the code formatting. Can you check to see whether it should all be a single block? It's rather confusing as it is right now.

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2018-01-10**:
Thank you gvdhooorn. This is a code snippet from a dll. What do you mean by should it all be a single block?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
There is limited space in the answer section, so perhaps the formatting as it is right now is not the best way to show us what you did / what is needed.

Adding some whitespace (or removing it) might improve things.

Also: do the comments go with the function *before* or *after* them?

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2018-01-10**:
I hope that it is much better.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
This is awesome. Thanks for updating the formatting.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
One nitpick though: I don't believe `111.222.0.1121:11411` is a valid IP:PORT combo?

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2018-01-10**:
No it isn't. I toke a radom number

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
That's fine, but an IP octet with 4 digits (`1121`) is going to confuse some future readers :)

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2018-01-10**:
You are right. Changed it